# Is $\frac{2^x}{4x+5}$ rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this expressional rational? Because my book says is yes, but doesn't provide a explaination as to why. $$\frac{2^x}{4x+5}$$

Comment: What's the domain of $x$?

Comment: The domain of x is not stated in the book. It just says circle the rational expression below.

Comment: Well, at $x = 0.5$ the expression evaluates to $\sqrt 2 \over 7$.

Comment: It however says $\frac{5x}{x+2}$ is rational.

Comment: Sounds like a typo, a rational expression needs to be polynomial (only includes $x^{<integer>}$ components) in both the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: What is the *definition* of rational in your book?

Comment: Each rational function $R(x)$ has the property that for some positive integer $n$ we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{R(x)}{x^n} = 0.$ (This is not hard to show once limits have been covered.) However, no such positive integer $n$ works for the function you gave (for each positive integer $n,$ using $n-1$ applications of L'Hopital's rule shows the limit to be $+\infty),$ so the function you gave is not rational.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about **rational functions**, then no, this is not a rational function of $x$, because of the $2^x$ which is not a polynomial.

Answer (score -1):

If we assume $x \in\mathbb{N}$ since rational numbers are the set $\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{p}{q},p\in \mathbb{Z},q\in \mathbb{N}\}$
$$2^x\in \mathbb{Z}\\4x+5 \in \mathbb{N}-\{\frac{5}{4}\}$$
Clearly $2^x$ is a integer if $x$ is natural,same applies for $4x+5$ so this is a rational number though I'm not sure if this is what you're asked to do,if you're asked if this is a rational expression then no.